# Untented via close to ground paddle

Tags: pcb-assembly, via, solder-paste, solder-mask

I have designed a board and found an open (untented) via very close to a ground paddle as shown below -

[image]
The via in question is DVDD12 (shown to the center-right. I am going with a stencil based assembly and there is a strong possibility that the via can short with the ground paddle during the reflow process.

How can I resolve this without a re-spin ? The board is fabricated but not assembled.The assembly house is saying that they can coat the via with solder mask and do the assembly.
Is that a good option and is it possible ?
Can I paste Kapton tape over the via and the paddle part thats next to the via ? Would that work ? Which is the best approach ?

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose it is a problem at all. A proper reflow wouldnt lead to a bridge there, as the via will wick all excess solder into its hole. Think of the gap as a strong repulsive force for solder and two strong wicking forces on each side (via hole and the grounded tab). It will rip the bridge in two.

Comment: @tobalt - Thank you for your comment. Also, let say I want to coat solder mask on the via, will that be possible ? Is it a straightforward procedure ?

Comment: How will the via DVDD12 be in the way in a reflow process? There won't be solder paste on these vias I guess.
But **if** it is, maybe you can apply silkscreen on top of the via?

Comment: @Radiofreak1041- you mean solder mask, right ?
The distance between DVVDD12 and the rectangle GND paddle is merely 0.15mm. Hence the concern of a solder bridge. ARe you refering to solder mask when you are saying silk screen ?
My worry is the short distance and the possibility of an accidental solder bridge.

Comment: I have added the image of the via in question.

Comment: If the exposed component pad covers this via, then there is a problem. but if the exposed pad is fully in the ground tab, I would try it.. Just try it on one board with one IC "at home" before sending the batch to the reflow house. Of course you could paint it with something by hand if it is not too many boards